# «Блаженны нищие духом...»

Tags: фразеология, значение-слов

Понятие "нищие духом" сейчас для многих является камнем преткновения. Я знаю, что трактуют его в корне неправильно: мол, это духовно бедные люди. В Библии же имеется в виду нечто другое.
Я слышала версию о том, что это те, кто нищи по духу, то есть бессребреники. Я права? Поясните, пожалуйста, точно значение этого выражения, чтобы я могла аргументированно спорить.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если для аргументированного спора, то из тех трактовок, что я слышал наиболее удобной для апологетов христианства является следующая: Нищие духом - это те, кто знает, что у человека нет ничего, чем бы он мог хвалиться перед Богом, но также нет ничего, что он не мог бы надеяться получить от милосердия Божия. Этакая духовная нищета, жажда познания.

Подобная трактовка вполне допустима, в восточной традиции вообще нищим по отношению к более высокому  по положению члену общества является любой представитель менее почётного сословия, независимо от богатства. Даже правитель в восточном представлении нищ перед б(Б)огом. Не могу с уверенность утверждать, что подобное обобщение применимо к Иудее I века нашей эры, но насколько я знаю историю этого периода, очень похоже, что восточное сознание в регионе было всё же определяющим.

Правда мне самому подобная трактовка кажется сомнительной, так как  при таком толковании первая категория блаженных (*нищие духом*) и чётвёртая (*алчущие и жаждущие праведности*) по сути совпадают, да и в наиболее ранних списках никаких "духом" не было, что опять таки говорит в пользу версии о том, что имелись в виду вполне конкретная категория людей, рабы и бедный люд, среди которых  первоначально и распространялось христианство.

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Не люблю Кураева, но все же он отражает официальную точку зрения.  
  
>Итак, нищие Ветхого Завета — это люди определенного духовного склада, те, кто всецело связал свою судьбу с поиском и исполнением воли Бога.  
  
http://www.pravmir.ru/nishhie-duxom/

Answer (score 2):

Почему именно *нищие духом*, а не просто "нищие"? Человек может в силу тех или иных причин побираться, просить милостыню - и быть при этом жадным, завистливым негодяем.
*Нищий духом* - абсолютный нестяжатель, он может иметь большие средства и возможности, но использует их на благо других, забывая свои нужды. Кто без раздумий отдает любую часть своего имущества/богатства (примеры известны), тот по праву *наследует царствие небесное*...

Answer (score 1):

Выражение "нищий духом" может иметь два смысла: А) богатый материально, но при этом нищий духовно; Б) нищий (нестяжатель)по духовному убеждению. Речь в Нагорной проповеди идет именно о БЕДНЫХ, а не о богатых  людях: «Блаженны нищие духом, ибо их есть Царство Небесное».  Блаженны изгнанные за правду, ибо их есть Царство Небесное".Следовательно, это люди, которые добровольно избирали бедность.

ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА
 В греческом оригинале Евангелия от Луки (6:20) сказано просто «нищие»,  без прибавления «духом» (как это  сделано в русском и славянском переводах). Потому что «анавим»(множественное от  «ани» - бедный, нищий)и без слова дух (греч. пневма, «дыхание жизни», которое Бог «вдунул» в Адама), имело тот же смысл. Вполне вероятно, что слово «духом» ДОБАВЛЕНО евангелистом Матфеем (или его переводчиком на греческий) для того, чтобы подчеркнуть нравственный аспект этого состояния.

Answer (score 0):

**"Блаженны нищие, ибо их есть Царство Небесное"**. Без слова ***"духом"*** - совершенно другой смысл написанного. Все нищие автоматом, без покаяния, попадают в Царствие Небесное, следовательно - блаженнее даже детей. Ну, теперь думайте, ересь это или истина.

Answer (score 0):

Некоторые комментаторы пишут, что в Нагорной проповеди говорится об «анавим» (множественное от «ани» - бедный, нищий). И еще пишут, что «духом» было добавлено потом. Тут возникла путаница. Множественное от «ани» — «аниим», а «анавим» — это скромные, смиренные  (от "анава" - смирение). Если в первоисточнике были «анавим», то это многое объясняет. Но вот [НОВЫЙ ЗАВЕТ параллельно на иврите и русском](http://noviy-zavet1.blogspot.com/2009/01/blog-post.html). Там написано עניי רוח, а это явно нищие духом. И нет там «анавим». Однако не исключено, что это обратный перевод на иврит, а не первоисточник. Так что четкого ответа нет, одни предположения.

Answer (score 0):

В современном прочтении духовная нищета - умственная бедность. Свойственна умственно неполноценным людям, маленьким детям, а также животным, у которых ум отсутствует априори (если принимать животных как наших планетарных сожителей, а не источник пищи или "живые игрушки").  Они лишены естественных "человеческих" качеств: хитрости, подлости, зависти, гордыни, - а значит, достойны бескорыстной любви и блаженства Царства Божия. Конечно, в изначальном смысле это означало совсем другое, но нам сложно понять   это. Очень трудно признать себя "нищим" перед Богом, никчёмным,  не способным ни на что доброе,  хотя на самом деле так оно и есть.